# SQL Server table schema storage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I create a table on the secondary filegroup and I remove the file (`.ndf`) from that file group.

Where is my table schema stay because when I want to insert the data exception throws that no file found and when I remove the filegroup exception is an object is attached to that filegroup.

Can anyone tell me where is my table structure is saved?

Comment: Your ask is not clear,Please try to elaborate what you are doing

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you presented this as a series of *steps* to reproduce what you're talking about. I'd imagine step 1 would be `CREATE DATABASE ...`.

Comment: The table metadata is part of the system tables and always lives in the primary filegroup. So no, you cannot just throw away filegroups and also have all tables in that filegroup go away (which is a good thing, as such an operation would be unsafe in general if there are dependencies, so you need to be explicit about what you want to do with the table -- by dropping it, for example).